# How to write dataframe (obtained from hive table) into hadoop SequenceFile and RCFile?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am able to write it into

- `ORC`
- `PARQUET`

  directly and
- `TEXTFILE`
- `AVRO`

using additional dependencies from databricks.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample code:

```
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
    DataFrame df = hc.table(hiveTableName);
    df.printSchema();
    DataFrameWriter writer = df.repartition(1).write();

    if ("ORC".equalsIgnoreCase(hdfsFileFormat)) {
        writer.orc(outputHdfsFile);

    } else if ("PARQUET".equalsIgnoreCase(hdfsFileFormat)) {
        writer.parquet(outputHdfsFile);

    } else if ("TEXTFILE".equalsIgnoreCase(hdfsFileFormat)) {
        writer.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(outputHdfsFile);

    } else if ("AVRO".equalsIgnoreCase(hdfsFileFormat)) {
        writer.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputHdfsFile);
    }
```

Is there any way to write dataframe into hadoop SequenceFile and RCFile?

Comment: what kind of sequence file ? csv , json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `void saveAsObjectFile(String path)` to save a `RDD` as a SequenceFile of serialized objects. So in your case you have to to retrieve the `RDD` from the `DataFrame`:

```
JavaRDD<Row> rdd = df.javaRDD;
rdd.saveAsObjectFile(outputHdfsFile);
```

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I don't think Spark supports writing into RCFiles out of the box, after skimming through the documentation. I suppose you have to use something like Parquet.

Comment: @dev ツ Could you mark this as an answer if it answered your question?